# Pretending to be an FBI profiler in Resurrection

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, resurrection

In [Resurrection (1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_(1999_film)), the serial killer successfully pretends to be an FBI profiler and gets access to all the information the police has about his murderers. Later, the police finds that he is not an FBI profiler and arrests him for impersonation, without being able to prove he is the serial killer. Then the judge let the serial killer get out of jail after paying a $20,000 bail.

Is the judge decision realistic? I think that pretending to be an FBI agent is a *really* serious crime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the judge decision realistic? I think that pretending to be an FBI agent is a really serious crime...

Certainly one can argue that impersonating a Federal Agent is a serious crime BUT until the person is **convicted** of the offence they are entitled to be considered **innocent**.

As such, if the judge decides that the accused is not a risk to the public and is likely to turn up for trial then bail is not *unreasonable*.

One should also be aware that the Penalty is only:

> An individual convicted of impersonating a federal agent may receive a fine and up to three years in prison.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/impersonating-a-federal-agent-penalty.html)</sup>

Clearly there is some plot-dependent things going on here but the answer is that this is **realistic**.